# Finding 2nd Order Linear ODE for known signal of summed oscillators starting at different times?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, oscillatory-integral

I have a signal which is a sum of $N$ cosines that oscillate between 0 and 1 and that start at different times. More specifically, I have

$$N(t) = \sum_{n=1}^N H(t - t_n) \Big[\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \cos(\omega(t - t_n)) \Big]$$

where $H()$ is the Heaviside step function, $\{t_n\}_{n=1}^N$ are known, fixed scalars all greater than 0 and $N(0) = 0$. I'd like to know what second order linear differential equation has this function $N(t)$ as its solution. How could I figure this out?

Disclaimer: Despite how my question may sound, I promise it isn't a homework problem. It's a problem that I want to solve for my research in Bayesian inference.

Comment: On any interval not containing a $t_k$ the function $f=N-n{1 \over 2}$ will satisfy $\ddot{f} = -f$, so $f$ will need to be redefined on each interval.

Comment: As a start, consider the inhomogenous solutions to $y''(t)+ y(t)=\delta(t-t_1)+\delta(t-t_2)+\cdots$. This produces the sum of cosines. To get the constant in each term consider $y''(t)+ y(t)=H(t-t_1)+\delta(t-t_1)+H(t-t_2)+\delta(t-t_2)+\cdots$